# Outlook AddIn - How to get notified when a folder is removed?

Tags: outlook, add-in, outlook-addin

the FolderRemoveEventHandler isn't global, it can just be used to notify when a folder is removed from the top level of a specific folders collection. I need an event to fire when any folder is removed/deleted - does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not, but there is nothing stopping you from recursively registering for all the folders events at application start.